# Constrain elements of a type-level list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a type family I can use to constrain the elements of a type level list. I have this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, DataKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (KnownSymbol, symbolVal)
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))

type family AllHave (c :: k -> Constraint) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint
type instance AllHave c '[] = ()
type instance AllHave c (x ': xs) = (c x, AllHave c xs)

type family Head (xs :: [k]) :: k where
    Head (x ': xs) = x

headProxy :: proxy xs -> Proxy (Head xs)
headProxy _ = Proxy

test :: AllHave KnownSymbol xs => proxy xs -> String
test p = symbolVal (headProxy p)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ test (Proxy :: Proxy '["a", "b"])
```

From what I understand this should work, but when I compile ghc spits out this:

```
Test.hs:18:10:
    Could not deduce (KnownSymbol (Head xs))
      arising from a use of ‘symbolVal’
    from the context (AllHave KnownSymbol xs)
      bound by the type signature for
                 test :: AllHave KnownSymbol xs => proxy xs -> String
      at Test.hs:17:9-52
    In the expression: symbolVal (headProxy p)
    In an equation for ‘test’: test p = symbolVal (headProxy p)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `Head` does not reduce when fed `xs` in `test` so Haskell has no way to deduce `KnownSymbol (Head xs)` from `AllHave KnownSymbol xs`. And it shouldn't: what should happen in case `xs` is empty?

To solve this problem, you can make it explicit that `xs` is not empty like so:

```
test :: AllHave KnownSymbol (x ': xs) => proxy (x ': xs) -> String
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. As a follow up question - what would this look like if I did want to provide a base case for empty `xs`, and define `test` recursively over the whole list instead of just the head?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about type families, so I'll point you to [gallais's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32419092/1477667) for an explanation of what went wrong in your code. Here is a very different approach, with a number of demo functions. There might be better ways; I don't know.

```
data CList :: (k -> Constraint) -> [k] -> * where
  CNil :: CList c '[]
  CCons :: c t => proxy t -> CList c ts -> CList c (t ': ts)

mapCSimple :: (forall a . c a => Proxy a -> b) -> CList c as -> [b]
mapCSimple f CNil = []
mapCSimple f (CCons (t :: proxy t) ts) = f (Proxy :: Proxy t) : mapCSimple f ts

toStrings :: CList KnownSymbol v -> [String]
toStrings = mapCSimple symbolVal

class KnownSymbols (xs :: [Symbol]) where
  known :: proxy xs -> CList KnownSymbol xs

instance KnownSymbols '[] where
  known _ = CNil

instance (KnownSymbol x, KnownSymbols xs) => KnownSymbols (x ': xs) where
  known _ = CCons Proxy $ known Proxy

exampleG :: KnownSymbols xs => proxy xs -> String
exampleG p = show . toStrings $ known p
```

This gives

```
> putStrLn $ exampleG (Proxy :: Proxy '["Hello", "Darkness"])
["Hello","Darkness"]
```

To get something more like what you sought,

```
cHead :: CList c (a ': as) -> Dict (c a)
cHead (CCons prox _) = Dict

test :: forall x xs . CList KnownSymbol (x ': xs) -> String
test xs = case cHead xs of Dict -> symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy x)

test2 :: (KnownSymbols xs, xs ~ (y ': ys)) => proxy xs -> String
test2 prox = test (known prox)
```

This gets

```
> putStrLn $ test2 (Proxy :: Proxy '["Hello", "Darkness"])
Hello
```

And here's another fun function:

```
data HList :: (k -> *) -> [k] -> * where
  HNil :: HList f '[]
  HCons :: f a -> HList f as -> HList f (a ': as)

mapC :: (forall a . c a => Proxy a -> f a) -> CList c as -> HList f as
mapC f CNil = HNil
mapC f (CCons (t :: proxy t) ts) = HCons (f (Proxy :: Proxy t)) (mapC f ts)
```